# React native Running components as soon as possible

Tags: react-native

I am new to RN and maybe I may be wrong on some terminologies used. I want to pass a data/run from one component to another. On my example, lets say I have : `Component 1, Component 2, and Component 3`. From Component 1, I pass data or access to Component 2 via `navigation.push('Component1') . . .`

This is my Component 2:

```
<SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'black'}}>
  .....
  <ComponentThree
    data={data}
    data2={data2}
  />
  ....
</SafeAreaView>
```

How do I run ComponentThree as soon as I enter ComponentTwo?

Edit: ComponentThree is clickable.

Edit2: All 3 components are different screens.

Comment: is component three a separate screen or all the components (1, 2, 3) are in the same screen?

Comment: Component 2 and 3 are the same screen. Component 1 is different

Comment: Sorry please diregard. They are all different screens